# Condition filtering within starting and ending point

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have 2 strings as below:

```
test1 = "<div>/*abc*/</div>";
test2 = "<div>/*abc*/Contents/*efg*/</div>";
```

I need to eliminate all `/*...*/`, `div` will remove if the `div` contains only `/*...*/`.
The following is regex i did:

```
Regex rx1 = new Regex(@"<div>/\*[^>]+\*/(</div>|<br/></div>|<br></div>)");
TemplateEditorFormatted = rx1.Replace(TemplateEditorFormatted, match => { return String.Empty; });
```

for string `test1`, it return correct result, which remove all.

But for `test2`, it also remove all contents. estimated result should not remove anything.

**UPDATED** (For learning)

for test 2, if i want to eliminate /*..*/ but not whole div. how the regex look like?

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions on HTML. Regular Expressions only work on regular languages, and HTML is a context-free language. It may work for very small specific examples, but it shouldn't be used because it will not work in general practice.

Comment: [Ask this guy about using regular expressions on HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using negative lookahead assertions:

```
@"<div>/\*(?:.(?!\*/))*\*/(</div>|<br/></div>|<br></div>)"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The part of interest is `(?:.(?!\*/))*`.

1. The `(?:foo)` is simply a *non-capturing group*—for now you can pretend it's just `(foo)`.
2. The `.` is a *wildcard* and matches any single character.
3. The `(?!bar)` is known as a *negative lookahead assertion*—it matches if `bar` does *not* follow, and is a *zero-width expression*, *i.e.* it doesn't consume any characters while matching.

So, the idea is to match a string of characters, `.`, that are *not* followed by `*/`, and only *then* the `*/</div>`.

Comment: Ur code work for me, THX! but if i want to select and remove /*..*/ only in test2? what the regex look like? means it will remove whole div if contains only /*..*/, if div contains other char then eliminate only /*..*/. possible to do?

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably not possible to do with a single regex. I don't think even C# supports variable-width lookbehind assertions, which is what you'd need. But you probably shouldn't be doing this with regex anyway. Instead, build a loop to find `<div>...</div>`s first, then replace `@"/\*.*?\*/"` within each div. (That `?` makes the `*` _non-greedy_.)

Answer (score 1):

why to do it in one step? imho it is much more readable in two steps:

```
string s1 = "<div>/*abc*/</div>";
string s2 = "<div>/*abc*/Contents/*efg*/</div>";

Regex findComments = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/");
Regex findEmptyDivs = new Regex(@"<div></div>");

s1 = findComments.Replace(s1, "");
s1 = findEmptyDivs.Replace(s1, "");

s2 = findComments.Replace(s2, "");
s2 = findEmptyDivs.Replace(s2, "");
```